# Plotting particles with coordinates from a multidimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib, animation, plot

I'm pretty new to Python which is why I wasn't able to solve my problem even though similar questions have been asked and there are plenty of documentations about this topic out there. So please have mercy with a programming-newbie.:)

Actually all I want to do is plotting particles in a movie-like style. I have all the coordinates for every particle and every step already listed in a list which contains two-dimensional arrays: one for every time step contains further arrays with the coordinates.
Later we are planning to put geometrical shapes into the flow to simulate how vortexes ect. emerge.

I've managed to plot my results with matplotlib in a for-loop which is working but not looking smoothly. Perfect would be if I was able to save the result as a video.

I greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: Please share the code that you have so far, and its expected output.

Comment: Please read the following documentation, then [edit] and rephrase the question. [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) & [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Always [Provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example (e.g. code, data, errors) as text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) & you're expected to [try to solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).